# How to check that scikit learn is installed in your system?

Tags: python-2.7

I have Scikit-Learn installed on my system. How can I check its version and its availability in my system?

Comment: a google search for scikit documentation should suffice

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501072/how-to-check-which-version-of-nltk-scikit-learn-installed)

As mentioned there you can do this from a Python REPL:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

If scikit-learn is not found on your system, you will get an `ImportError: No module named sklearn`. If scikit-learn was installed inside a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/), you will need to make sure it is activated via `source bin/activate` from the virtualenv root directory.